# I keep getting "table or view does not exist " in oracle- live

Tags: sql, oracle

i am working on Oracle live (online version) and i created the fact table, however i keep getting this error. "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"
I have also broken down the queries but i still get the error.

```
create table fact_table(    
    customer_id number not null,    
    order_id number not null,    
    product_id number not null,    
    employee_id number not null,    
    unit_price number not null,    
    quantity number not null,    
    order_total number not null,    
    salary number not null,    
    commission_pct number,   
CONSTRAINT FK_Customers_dim    
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customers_dim(customer_id),    
CONSTRAINT FK_Order_dim    
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES Order_dim(order_id),    
CONSTRAINT FK_Employees_dim    
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES Employees_dim(employee_id),    
CONSTRAINT FK_product_dim    
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_dim(product_id), 
 constraints pk_fact_table  
primary key (customer_id , order_id, product_id ,employee_id)
```

);

Answer (score 1):

I get the same, running it in my database:

```
SQL> create table fact_table(
  2      customer_id number not null,
  3      order_id number not null,
  4      product_id number not null,
  5      employee_id number not null,
  6      unit_price number not null,
  7      quantity number not null,
  8      order_total number not null,
  9      salary number not null,
 10      commission_pct number,
 11  CONSTRAINT FK_Customers_dim
 12      FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customers_dim(customer_id),
 13  CONSTRAINT FK_Order_dim
 14      FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES Order_dim(order_id),
 15  CONSTRAINT FK_Employees_dim
 16      FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES Employees_dim(employee_id),
 17  CONSTRAINT FK_product_dim
 18      FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_dim(product_id),
 19   constraints pk_fact_table
 20  primary key (customer_id , order_id, product_id ,employee_id));
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customers_dim(customer_id),
                                         *
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

So, what does it mean? It means that table(s) you **reference** should be created BEFORE this one; otherwise, you can't create foreign key constraints.